# How to create a new google doc for every iteration?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've just created a google script that pulls the data from a google sheet and imports it into specific spots that have been declared in a google doc, i.e. the column "name" has a value of "Melanie Perkins" and replaces the value "name" inside the google doc with that name.

But, when I run the script it just pulls the data from the first row (company, address, name) and then creates the google doc. However, I have multiple rows and want to create a new google doc for each row but can't seem to get it to work. That's the code and screenshots of the google doc and sheet that I've used.

[Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPi8s.png)

[Google Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZtFN.png)

```
function docsAutomation() {
  let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  
  // opens spreadsheet
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Eu4iiINGM6ytxfLdEznRmwq__qxTfuaJF6cNW5LVOYQ');

  // duplicates the file
  let documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1IlzS3CWQsDjxMw8b6TvgdoeJqOOb8HZpH7B8kl5ZmaE').makeCopy().getId();
  
  // renames the copied file
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('timo_huennebeck_' + date);  
  
  let fullDocument = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
  let range = ss.getRange("A2:C4");
  fullDocument.replaceText('##personalName##', 'Timo');

  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

    cell = range.getCell(i, 1);
    business = cell.getValue(); 
    fullDocument.replaceText('##business' + i + '##', business);

    cell = range.getCell(i, 2);
    address = cell.getValue();
    fullDocument.replaceText('##address' + i + '##', address);

    cell = range.getCell(i, 3);
    name = cell.getValue();
    fullDocument.replaceText('##name' + i + '##', name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A new doc for each row.

You are also missing a field so I assumed it is next column

```
function docsAutomation() {
  const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Eu4iiINGM6ytxfLdEznRmwq__qxTfuaJF6cNW5LVOYQ');
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let id = DriveApp.getFileById('1IlzS3CWQsDjxMw8b6TvgdoeJqOOb8HZpH7B8kl5ZmaE').makeCopy().getId();
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).setName('timo_huennebeck_' + date);
    let body = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody();
    body.replaceText(`##business##`, r[0]);
    body.replaceText('##address##', r[1]);
    body.replaceText('##name##', r[2]);
    body.replaceText('##personalName##', r[3]);//do not see any data for this
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah, I had messed it up in the code as the ##personalName## was just in the google doc file but not in the google sheets. It's all working like a charm now. Thanks a lot!